# sending ctrl c over serial in Processing

Tags: serial-port, processing, uart, msp430

I have a microcontroller (MSP430) that accepts command over serial in Processing. I can program it using text input box with commands. When I type "adc 4"  (to read values from the ADC) it streams the values off the adc.  To stop the string, the MSP430 expects a <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> but I've been unable to send <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to work.

How can I send this string in processing?

```
port = new Serial(this, Serial.list()[9], 9600);

String output = "";
void keyPressed() {
if (key < 255) {
  output += str(key);
  if (key == lf) {

    if (output.indexOf("ctrl")==0) {
      port.write(0x03);  //ctrl+c doesn't work
    }

    print("sending: " + output);
    port.write(output);
    port.write(0x0d);  //send CR
    output = "";
  }
}

// Process a line of text from the serial port.
void serialEvent(Serial p) {
  input = p.readStringUntil('\n');
  print("received: " + input);
}

// Draw the input and ouput buffers and a little help.
void draw() {
  background(0);
  fill(204, 102, 0);
  text("Type a line of text to send to the serial port:", 10, 20);
  fill(255, 255, 255);
  rect(10, 75, 480, 5);
  text(output, 10, 55);
  text(input, 10, 110);
}
```

I tried to add a clause to detect if <kbd>CTRL</kbd> was entered in the textbox, and if <kbd>CTRL</kbd> was entered to send out <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> over serial. Processing does not seem to send out the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and it doesn't interrupt the msp430 as it does if I use coolTerm.

Comment: What output do you get? Do you see "sending: ctrl"? What input are you supplying? Divide the problem space in half. First, you have to decide to send a control-C. Second, you have to send it. Which of these is failing?

Comment: Hi @DavidSchwartz, I am trying to send control-C through the UART, but it appears Processing doesn't interrupt the code.

Comment: The input I am supplying is "ctrl+c". And it says "sending ctrl+c". But it doesn't seem to be sending out the ctrl+c to interrupt the msp430, which is in the middle of streaming adc values.

Comment: You're sure it expected a control C and not an RS232 break sequence?

Comment: The command line interface document that I received says "adc.channel [times]. Read ADC in mV; ^C to stop"  So if I type in "adc 4" it streams back data (e.g."Ch4 = 01C2","Ch4 = 01C3" ) until I press "Control+C" on my mac. But when I try to get Processing to send out "Control+C" it  never stops streaming, so I don't think Processing is sending out the Control C.